# Clone problem in IE7. Please note I can't change the HTML

Tags: jquery

I need to clone a button in a frame(AssessmentsIFrame) whose id is “wpv_1266351” to a td and I need to clone a div in a frame(AssessmentsIFrame) whose name is “titlediv_1266230” to a second td in a table.
I am using the following statements to achieve it but it is not working in IE7.(It is working in Firefox)

$('#AssessmentsIFrame').contents().find('#wpv_1266351').clone().appendTo('#AssessmentRequestFormButton');
                                    $('#AssessmentsIFrame').contents().find('#titlediv_1266230').clone().appendTo('#MedicalBriefButtons');

Can someone please help me with this? It should work in Firefox and IE. Please note I can't change the HTML.

```
<div id="button-cus"><input type="button" onclick="_openpageview(1266351,'bGZLNEFJBxs9RFYgPUNMJQIGEhAyUgowH2JdVERBZF4~',1)" value="Open" id="wpv_1266351" name="wpv_1266351" class="Button"></div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the console?

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant to your problem or not, but you have two td's with the same id "td1", which is invalid HTML.

Comment: I am getting an error on clone function.

Answer (score 0):

```
oFrame = $('#AssessmentsIFrame')[0];
$('#wpv_1266351', oFrame.contentDocument).clone().appendTo('#AssessmentRequestFormButton');
$('#titlediv_1266230', oFrame.contentDocument).clone().appendTo('#MedicalBriefButtons');
```

Why are you making it so hard for yourself? I suppose you use your id's unique, so why checking for another id's content instead of just selecting the ID you want? Make sure you change your clone's id after creating it, so your ids stay unique. Good luck!

-edit-

over-read the fact that you used an iFrame.

Comment: The button is in a frame named AssessmentsIFrame